# "Moving" sequential containers to pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, cpp-core-guidelines

I'm building a buffer for network connections where you can explicitly allocate memory or you can supply it on your own via some sequential container(eg.:std::vector,std::array)these memory chunks are stored in a list what we use later for read/write operations. (the chunks are needed for handle multiple read/write requests) 
I have a question about the last part, I want to make a pointer to the container's data and then tell the container to not care about it's data anymore. 
So something like move semantics.

```
std::vector<int> v = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
std::vector<int> _v(std::move(v));
```

Where `_v` has all the values of `v` and `v` left in a safe state.

The problem is if I just make a pointer for `v.data()` after the lifetime of the container ends, the data pointed by the pointer releases with the container. 
For example:

```
// I would use span to make sure It's a sequential container 
// but for simplicity i use a raw pointer
// gsl::span<int> s;
int *p;
{
   std::vector<int> v = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
   // s = gsl::make_span(v);
   p = v.data();
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    std::cout << p[i] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;
```

Now `p` contains some memory trash and i would need the memory previously owned by the vector.

I also tried `v.data() = nullptr` but `v.data()` is rvalue so it's not possible to assign it. Do you have any suggestions, or is this possible?

edit.: 
To make it more clear what i'm trying to achieve:

```
class readbuf_type
{
    struct item_type // representation of a chunk
    {
        uint8_t * const data;
        size_t size;

        inline item_type(size_t psize)
            : size(psize)
            , data(new uint8_t[psize])
        {}

        template <std::ptrdiff_t tExtent = gsl::dynamic_extent>
        inline item_type(gsl::span<uint8_t,tExtent> s)
            : size(s.size())
            , data(s.data())
        {}

        inline ~item_type()
        { delete[] data; }
    };

    std::list<item_type> queue; // contains the memory
public:

    inline size_t read(uint8_t *buffer, size_t size); // read from queue

    inline size_t write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size); // write to queue

    inline void *get_chunk(size_t size)
    {   
        queue.emplace_back(size);
        return queue.back().data;
    }

    template <std::ptrdiff_t tExtent = gsl::dynamic_extent>
    inline void put_chunk(gsl::span<uint8_t,tExtent> arr)
    { 
        queue.emplace_back(arr);
    }
} readbuf;
```

I have the `get_chunk`function what basically just allocates memory with the size, and I have `put_chunk` what I'm struggling with, the reason i need this because before you can write to this queue you need to allocate memory and then copy all the elements from the buffer(vector,array) you're trying to write from to the queue.
Something like:

```
std::vector<int> v = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
// instead of this
readbuf.get_chunk(v.size);
readbuf.write(v.data(), v.size());

// we want this
readbuf.put_chunk({v});
```

Since we're developing for distributed systems memory is crucial and that's why we want to avoid the unnecessary allocation, copying.

ps.This is my first post, so sorry if i wasn't precise in the first place..

Comment: It's not possible with standard containers, but why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to overcome exactly (I don't see how the code relates to the rest of your question). But I think it might help you to know that, barring allocator incompatibilities, a pointer to `v.data();` will point to `v_.data();` if you move `v` into `v_`.

Comment: Are you asking to "move" the content of a vector into a pointer? Do you want `p` to own the data that `v` used to hold?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's not guaranteed and relying on it would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA [Seems like it is guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D#Notes).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux exactly, without any allocation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was not aware of blanket guarantee, thank you for sharing.

Comment: @marko1777 It's not possible to "release" a vector's data to a raw pointer like that as far as I know. Using `p` after `v`'s lifetime ends is undefined behavior, though I don't doubt that this UB exhibited itself as producing the result you expect (appeared to work). This won't last, any change to your code or the context it runs in could change the behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It can be with a custom allocator right? Although the things you would have to do to the memory would be dubious at best.

Comment: This is correct. This is not doable with standard containers per se. You will have to implement your own custom containers. The custom container can be nothing more than a single `struct` with a `unique_ptr` to the `std::vector` with the real data, and the "not caring any more" consists of nothing more than moving the `unique_ptr` somewhere else.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Interesting. It might be possible that way, but I'm just not sure. I'm not familiar enough with the constraints on what an allocator is allowed to do and what it isn't allowed to do. If it *is* allowed, it doesn't seem like a great idea to me though, in terms of the design decisions it implies.

Comment: Change `int *p;` to be a `std::vector<int>` instead of a `int*`.  Then use `p = std::move(v);` instead of `p = v.data();`.

Comment: @Quentin I updated the question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wanted to avoid the questions about "why i want to this" but i should have post some code instead of plain text, I will definitely do that first next time..
Also can you tell me what's an UB?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't 100% understand, your point what do you mean moving the `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @marko1777 UB is Undefined Behavior. UB occurs when you write code for which the standard that defines the language either doesn't specify what happens or specifically says that it results in undefined behavior. The compiler is not required or expected to detect these errors and usually won't emit any warning or error. There is no way to predict what your code will do if it encounters UB until you compile it and try. Different compilers, different version, different runs, different flags or any other change can alter the behavior. It must never be relied on, it's presence is always an error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh, I haven't seen this abbreviation before, thank you for explaining! :)

Comment: Why is this question tagged cpp-core-guidelines? I think that tag should/can be removed.

Comment: @WernerHenze Because it uses gsl::span

Comment: @marko1777 So what? With that argument you could also add vector, stl, loop and other tags. This question is not about cpp core guidelines. If it where about GSL, then it should be tagged guideline-support.library, but not cpp-core-guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to "steal" the buffer of the standard vector in the manner that you suggest - or any other standard container for that matter.

You've already shown one solution: Move the buffer into another vector, instead of merely taking the address (or another non-owning reference) of the buffer. Moving from the vector transfers the ownership of the internal buffer.

It would be possible to implement such custom vector class, whose buffer could be stolen, but there is a reason why vector doesn't make it possible. It can be quite difficult to prove the correctness of your program if you release resources willy-nilly. Have you considered how to prevent the data from leaking? The solution above is much simpler and easier to verify for correctness.

Another approach is to re-structure your program in such way that no references to the data of your container outlive the container itself (or any invalidating operation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated the question. Sadly there is no option to organize the code that way..

Comment: If you really want to do something like this instead of implementing a custom container, you can just implement a custom allocator what is the same as the standard one, but on deallocate it doesn't free the memory. 
I don't get the point why would leaking be a problem, because you deallocate the memory in the destructor when you destroy the object what contains it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the memory area of the vector cannot be detached from the std::vector object. The memory area can be deleted even if you insert some data to the std::vector object. Therefore use of this memory area later is not safe, unless you are sure that this particular std::vector object exists and is not modified.

The solution to this problem is to allocate a new memory area and copy the content of the vector to this newly allocated memory area. The newly allocated memory area can be safely accessed without worrying about the state of the std::vector object.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* p = new int[v.size()];
memcpy(p, v.data(), sizeof(int) * v.size());
```

Don't forget to delete the memory area after you are finished using this memory area.

```
delete [] p;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this would be a great idea but we should minimize the allocations. I edited my question so maybe it's more clear why I need this.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in thinking that the pointer "contains" memory. It doesn't contain anything, trash or ints or otherwise. It is a pointer. It points to stuff. You have deleted that stuff and not transferred it anywhere else, so it can't work any more.

In general, you will *need* a container to put this information in, be it another vector, or even your own hand-made array. Just having a pointer to data does not mean you have data.

Furthermore, since it is impossible to ask a vector to relinquish its buffer to a non-vector thing, a vector is really your only chance in this particular case. It's not quite clear why that's not a good enough solution for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you try to achieve but I would use moving semantic like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main() {
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> p; 
{
   std::vector<int> v = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
   p = std::move(make_unique<std::vector<int>>(v));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
   std::cout << (*p)[i] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```